Mac folder permission error 403 unable to access 'https: when I push to git
I don't understand how or why I cannot push my remote repository to Github from vs code.
git push -u origin main

The Error Received
remote: Permission to stvnplm8/Story.git denied to stvnplm.


The requested URL returned 403 Error.

I have tried getting opening the folder and altering permission to read and write only, But that didn't work I don't know if there is another way or if I am doing something wrong.
